# How can empty fields in a csv file be set to Missing when importing as a Dataset?

Tags: import, dataset, csv-format

When importing a csv file with empty fields as a `Dataset`, the empty fields are set to zero-length strings ("").  There is an option, `EmptyField`, which replaces the zero-length string with an arbitrary string, but I don't see a way to set empty fields to `Missing[]` or some other value indicating missing data.

The import code is:

```
data = Import["file.csv",{"CSV","Dataset"},"HeaderLines"->1, "EmptyField"->""]
```

The result is the same as leaving `EmptyField` out since "" is the default.  However, all attempts at setting `EmptyField` to `Missing[]`, `Null`, or `None` fail.  For example:

[image]

Is there a way to set empty fields to `Missing[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this using the "EmptyField" option. I post process after `Import`.

```
data /. "" -> Null
```

or

```
data /. "" -> Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.  It would be nice to have a more flexible option to handle missing data on import.